# Solution of recurrences containing powers of terms

Tags: sequences-and-series, recurrence-relations, generating-functions

Consider the recurrence $F_{n+1}=F_n^2+a$ (with $F_0$ known) for some integer $a$. What is the closed form solution to such a recurrence?

**Case: $a=0, \; F_0>0$**
$$ \begin{align} 
F_{n+1} & =F_n^2 \\
\ln F_{n+1}  & = 2 \ln F_n \\  
G_n  = \ln F_n & \implies G_{n+1} = 2G_n 
\end{align} $$
The solution to the final G_n recurrence is easily found using generating series:
$$ G_n = G_02^n \\ G_n=2^n \ln F_0$$
Thus, reversing the substitution:
$$ F_n=e^{G_n}=F_0^{2^n}$$
This can be extended with simple reasoning to all values of $F_0$. Thus it has been solved for $a=0$.

However, this logarithm method appears to break down when $a \neq 0$. I have tried manipulating generating series but have so far come up empty.

Does anyone have a solution, even only in special cases?  Any help would be appreciated ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general, there is *no* closed form solution for this equation. It is sometimes called the **quadratic map** and shows chaotic behavior for some values of $a$, i.e. the value of $F_n$ becomes ridiculously dependent on its initial value, $F_0$.

Some say that if an equation had a closed form solution, it wouldn't be chaotic. For more information see [this wiki page](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Fractals/Iterations_of_real_numbers/r_iterations#Real_quadratic_map) as well as [this page](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/QuadraticMap.html). Also [there is a great paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/math/9707224) on this special map that shows *almost every real quadratic map is either regular or stochastic*.

Comment: Great! Thanks. I spent 3 hours working on a problem with no closed solution... :P